# TCP- I can't send data when listening as a server

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp, socketexception

I can't send data when I listen over TCP.I need to listen all the time incoming connections and I should send some data whenever needed.My server code starts to listen when program loads,but when I try to send data it gives this error:

> "Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted (typically under load)."

And here is my code:

```
public void Send(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        String str = "08";
        String str2 = "4213";
        String CRCvalue = CRC("08" + str2);
        String str3 = str2 + CRCvalue;
         Connect("localhost", "hello localhost " + Guid.NewGuid());
    }
  static void Connect(String server, String message)
     {

             try
                {               
                      Int32 port = 2101;
                      TcpClient client = new TcpClient(server, port);             
                      Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
                      NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

                         // Send the message to the connected TcpServer. 
                       stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                       System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Sent");          
                       stream.Close();
                       client.Close();
              }
             catch (ArgumentNullException e)
             {
                 System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException: {0}", e);
             }
             catch (SocketException e)
             {
                 System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
             }}
      protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        CreateServer();
    }
      private static void CreateServer()
      {
          var tcp = new TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Any,25565);
          tcp.Start();



          var listeningThread = new Thread(() =>
          {
              while (true)
              {
                  var tcpClient = tcp.AcceptTcpClient();
                  ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(param =>
                  {
                      NetworkStream stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
                      string incomming;
                      byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
                      int i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                      incomming = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
                      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(incomming);
                      tcpClient.Close();
                  }, null);
              }
          });
```

Any help will be apprecitated.

Comment: Can you show the code where you "try to send data"? The code you have in the question only shows the method for sending a message and listening for some data, where is Connect() actually used?

You have not stated where the exception is thrown, is it in the Connect() method or the CreateServer() method?

Comment: Side note: be aware that TCP is a stream of bytes (in each direction), not messaging. There's no guarantee that what you get from a call of `Read` will be matched 1-1 with a call to `Write` at the other end.

Comment: I added it now.

Comment: And it throws the exception in createrServer() tcp.start() statement

Comment: The client part and the server part should be in different applications. So server part must be a separate exe file from the client part. You try to open twice your application. so the server is created one more time.

Answer (score 0):

The exception tells you that you are trying to open the same server socket more than once. You should close your `TcpListener` (and join the listening thread) on form close. You could also use a singleton service, which manages the tcp listener (or assign a static field and only create the listener if the field is not set).